# Get all combination of n vectors taken 2 vectors at a time

Tags: r

I have three vectors

```
a = 1:5
b = 6:10
c = 11:15
```

I want to get data.frames by taking all combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c` two at a time into a list. Below is my desired output.

```
list(cbind(a,b), cbind(a,c), cbind(b,c))
[[1]]
     a  b
[1,] 1  6
[2,] 2  7
[3,] 3  8
[4,] 4  9
[5,] 5 10

[[2]]
     a  c
[1,] 1 11
[2,] 2 12
[3,] 3 13
[4,] 4 14
[5,] 5 15

[[3]]
      b  c
[1,]  6 11
[2,]  7 12
[3,]  8 13
[4,]  9 14
[5,] 10 15
```

The following sort of works but I am wondering if there is a better way?

```
combn(x = c("a","b","c"), m = 2, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) eval(parse(text = y))))
```

Comment: `combn(list(a,b,c), 2, simplify=FALSE)` essentially

Comment: Or define `M=cbind(a,b,c)` and use combn to subset by various sets of cols.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, `M = data.frame(a,b,c); apply(X = combn(1:NCOL(M), 2), MARGIN = 2, function(x) M[,x])` worked

Comment: @d.b - `combn` has a `FUN=` argument - `combn(1:NCOL(M), 2, FUN=function(x) M[,x] )`

Comment: @thela Any idea how to get it to keep the col names in the result?

Comment: @Frank -  You can do something like `combn(mget(c("a","b","c")), 2, FUN=do.call, what=cbind, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was simplifying to mat instead of returning a list, since they print so similarly. `combn(1:NCOL(M), 2, FUN=function(x) M[,x], simplify = FALSE)` does it.

Comment: @Frank - I reckon that last one of yours is about as clean as you're going to do it :-)

Comment: @d.b I liked your answer here, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way (thanks to OP and @thelatemail for fixes):

```
M = cbind(a, b, c)
combn(seq_len(ncol(M)), 2, FUN = function(x) M[,x], simplify = FALSE)

[[1]]
     a  b
[1,] 1  6
[2,] 2  7
[3,] 3  8
[4,] 4  9
[5,] 5 10

[[2]]
     a  c
[1,] 1 11
[2,] 2 12
[3,] 3 13
[4,] 4 14
[5,] 5 15

[[3]]
      b  c
[1,]  6 11
[2,]  7 12
[3,]  8 13
[4,]  9 14
[5,] 10 15
```